# Why do we only talk about three options when it comes to the Shape of Spacetime?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, curvature, models

The shape of spacetime is a hotly debated topic which can determine how we understand the ultimate fate of the universe and many more things.  Despite this I only ever see factions supporting three shapes: Flat (Euclidean Geometry valid), Closed (Elliptic Geometry valid), Open (Hyperbolic Geometry valid).

Why only these three? What do we know about the Big Bang and inflation regarding the shape of spacetime? Why can't it be mixture of the three, to create infinitely many options?

Comment: Because the possible outcomes of a real number, k, directly associated with the curvature, can be <0, 0, >0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you're deriving the Robertson-Walker metric, you make an assumption that the universe is spatially homogenous and isotropic.  It is a theorem in geometry that there are only two three dimensional spaces that satisfy this assumption.

Of course, the real geometry of spacetime is going to depend on where individual stars and galaxies are, and will be much more complicated than this.  But the Robertson-Walker metric doesn't care about this, it just cares about the large-scale "smoothed-out" structure of spacetime, which observation says is smooth and uniform in all directions.

Comment: Why does this large-scale smoothed-out Spacetime need to be one of those three ones?

Comment: If the universe is isotropic and homogeneous then the curvature has to be the same everywhere and in all directions. That means it can be described by a single number, usually referred to as $k$. Because it's an ordinary number $k$ can only negative, zero or positive. All negative values of $k$ are open universes, all positive values of $k$ are closed universes and $k = 0$ is a flat universe. There are only three possibilities.

Comment: Okay. Means, those assumptions are the key.

Comment: That the universe is essentially homogeneous and isotropic on large scales is not an assumption but an observation. It's actually the key observation that requires us to jump trough the hoops of inflation, because it's not easy to reproduce from realistic initial conditions for the big bang.

Comment: @CuriousOne: when you construct the model, it's an assumption.  I agree that it's an observational fact (note my last sentence), at least to the extent that the void models have finally been completely ruled out.

Comment: @CuriousOne No, it is definitely an assumption that the laws of physics are the same elsewhere in the universe, since we can't go over there and check, only make observations from afar and hope that something weird isn't going on that affects our observations. (In fact, something weird *is* going on, and for the moment we're calling it dark matter.)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: dark matter is a local assumption to fix galactic data.  It is almost certainly present in the local galaxy, far below cosmological scales, and MOND models to "account" for it are more complicated than the dark matter assumption is.

Comment: And also, things like hydrogen absorption lines are the same in other galaxies, so we know that non-gravitational laws of physics are likely the same.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: The measurements if the CMB ARE a direct measurement of isotropy and you can sift through spectral data all day long without being able to detect any sign of inhomogeneity in the laws of physics. There are plenty of papers on the constancy of the fundamental constants as a function of cosmological time, too, and what deviations would mean for e.g. star formation, radionuclides etc.. None of these are assumptions, they are real world consequences of measurements we have done in the solar system and on objects all the way back to the surface of last scattering.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer We are observing that locally the (gravitational, at least) laws of physics can vary from one place to another, and so we call it "matter" and give a name to something we don't yet have a good model for, in order to preserve the foregone conclusion that "the laws of physics are the same everywhere". From this point of view, it's not even an assumption, but rather a base for how we view the data.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: like I said, we can use that data to assume that Newtonian theory is wrong (on DM scales, you're below relativity's applicability), and construct models about HOW it is wrong.  The result you get is more complicated than just assuming dark matter.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Correct me if I'm wrong (I may be confusing with dark energy), but isn't dark matter the thing that is bending light and affecting gravity on galactic scales? If so, then it is very much a GR issue.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: the light bending is observed in galactic clusters.  The gravitational rotation curve stuff happens near the outside of the galaxy, where motions are slow and overall forces are weak, and Newtonian mechanics is sufficient to model the rotation.  Of course, if MOND is true, then GR needs to be modified as well, but to describe the galactic rotation curves, you only need Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: Do you mean three three dimensional spaces (sphere, plane, hyperboloid)?